# How to hide an alias column in mysql EDITED

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is a replica of some question asked already, but i need some suggestion.

I know basics of MySQL, i have a query to calculate distance between latitude and longitude and based on minimum distance i am returning id's.

now i don't want the distance column as result of my query. How to do it.

Here is my query.

```
    select cl.wp_id,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.91841) ) * cos( radians( y(gproperty) ) ) * 
       cos( radians( x(gproperty)) - radians(77.58631) ) + sin( radians(12.91841) ) * 
       sin( radians(y(gproperty) ) ) ) ) AS distance 
from db1.geofeature gf, db2.c_loc cl where gf.o_type = 10 and cl.c_info_id = 23 
    and gf.o_id = cl.wp_id 
    having distance < 10 order by distance limit 10;
```

i want only my **cl.wp** to be displayed as result. How to do that.?

**EDIT**
now i have 3 tables how to join them.?

```
select dlo.id,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.9) ) * cos( radians( y(gproperty) ) ) * cos( radians( x(gproperty)) - radians(77.5) ) +sin( radians(12.9) ) * sin( radians(y(gproperty) ) ) ) ) AS distance from db1.gfeature dgf, db2.loc dlo, db2.cust dcu where gf.o_type = 6 and dcu.id = 240 and dgf.o_id = dlo.p_id having distance < 20 order by distance limit 10;
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: remove the column...thats it

Comment: Move the `distance` expression into where clause and remove having.

Comment: which column.? 
I used formula and name it as distance. based on that distance i'm ordering minimum.

Comment: Thanks all,

Gordon Linoff, modified my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to use a subquery:

```
select wp_id
from (select cl.wp_id,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.91841) ) * cos( radians( y(gproperty) ) ) * 
             cos( radians( x(gproperty)) - radians(77.58631) ) + sin( radians(12.91841) ) * 
             sin( radians(y(gproperty) ) ) ) ) AS distance
      from db1.geofeature gf join
           db2.c_loc cl 
           on gf.o_type = 256 and cl.c_info_id = 146 and gf.o_id = cl.wp_id
    ) t
where distance < 10
order by distance
limit 10;
```

Notice that I also fixed the join syntax to use explicit joins.

Comment: Thanks alot Gordon Linoff.

Can u suggest me any blog/site/resource so that i can learn more on MySQL.

Comment: @h.APP.y Here's the SQL section of MySQL Reference Manual - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html