# Hiding alias column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

It might be the repeated question but need help.
i am new to MySQL.

Here is my problem.

i have a query to calculate distance between latitude and longitude. based on the distance order i have to return id's.

```
SELECT dlo.id,
       (3959 * acos(cos(radians(12.9)) * cos(radians(y(gproperty))) * cos(radians(x(gproperty)) - radians(77.5)) +sin(radians(12.9)) * sin(radians(y(gproperty))))) AS distance
FROM db1.gfeature dgf,
     db2.loc dlo,
     db2.cust dcu
WHERE gf.o_type = 6
  AND dcu.id = 240
  AND dgf.o_id = dlo.p_id HAVING distance < 20
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10;
```

which returns as

```
+------+-----------------------+
| id   | distance              |
+------+-----------------------+
|  101 | 0.00025714756425665   |
|  199 | 0.10971525612556807   |
|  722 | 0.22772618588406165   |
+------+-----------------------+
```

But i need only id column to be displayed. I [asked same-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400438/how-to-hide-an-alias-column-in-mysql/24400458?noredirect=1#comment37743705_24400458) yesterday. But now i am using **three tables** to get data. So confused in joining 3 tables.

Can anybody suggest me.?

I tried this way

```
select id from (
  select 
    dlo.id,
    ( 3959 * acos(   cos( radians(12.9) ) 
                   * cos( radians( y(gproperty) ) )
                   * cos( radians( x(gproperty) ) - radians(77.5) )

                   + sin( radians(12.9) )
                   * sin( radians(y(gproperty) ) )
                 )
    ) AS distance 
  from db1.gfeature dgf 
       join db2.cust dcu, db2.loc dlo 
         on dgf.o_type = 6 and dcu.id = 10 and dgf.o_id = dlo.w_id
) t 
where distance < 10 
order by distance 
limit 10;
```

but getting syntax error near "on..."

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just remove the expression from the select list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide an alias column in mysql EDITED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400438/how-to-hide-an-alias-column-in-mysql-edited)

Comment: inline view might help you solve your problem

Comment: based on the distance calculated only i have to return id's without that expression how can i return id's.?

Comment: yeah.. repeated but here i am using 3 tables. So stucked in joining 3 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Just use subquery to achieve.

```
SELECT S.ID 
FROM
    (SELECT dlo.id,
           (3959 * acos(cos(radians(12.9)) * cos(radians(y(gproperty))) * cos(radians(x(gproperty)) - radians(77.5)) +sin(radians(12.9)) * sin(radians(y(gproperty))))) AS distance
    FROM db1.gfeature dgf, db2.loc dlo , db2.cust dcu
    WHERE gf.o_type = 6 AND dcu.id = 240 AND dgf.o_id = dlo.p_id 
    HAVING distance < 20) S 
ORDER BY S.distance 
LIMIT 10;
```